# Telnet cannot connect to localhost on port 23

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, telnet

I am using bat file assigned with vbs script to change router configuration every 15 minutes through the day through telnet commands. It works as supposed for a while then it shows this message
"Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed"
I can't open default gateway on web interface too, I can't even login through telnet or web interface until I power off/on router it self.
How I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to check the 'Services' console and verify the 'Telnet' service is running.
2. To isolate the issue, turnoff your Firewall and Antivirus software. If these security software blocks the telnet process, then add the rules to exclude this telnet process which is being blocked frequently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I said It works fine for sometime but after while -maybe over 5 hours- it hang and I cannot login to localhost until I power off/on router it self physically.

Comment: Checking the firewall is perfectly valid - Does the device have any sort of intrusion detection? It might see your constant connections as some sort of attack.

Comment: how do you check "services"

Comment: You can hit the start menu and use the run command box (or just type win+r to get the prompt) and type 'services' into the box and hit enter. That will open the applet. If it is installed, you'll find it in 'services (local)'.